# convert excel to pdf using itext API programmatically in java

Tags: java, excel, pdf, itext

I am looking for utility to convert Excel to PDF using iText API. Find many sources like this ([Convert excel to pdf using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259952/convert-excel-to-pdf-using-itext)) but not working out for huge data in Excel (around 15 MB excel file with 18 columns and 15,00,000 rows) as it is giving Out of memory exception. Need an utility to transform xlsx file and store it as PDF in local drive.